# tf tree problem with map->odom->base_link

Tags: navigation, rviz, gazebo-plugins, map-to-odom, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a problem with providing the following relationship "**map->odom->base_link"** in my tf tree. My question is what changes are necessary to fix this problem. In the below sections I will show what I have done.

I have added the following plugins to the .gazebo file.

```
<!-- GPS plugin -->
<plugin name="robot_gps_sim" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>4.0</updateRate>
  <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
  <topicName>gps</topicName>
  <velocityTopicName>gps_velocity</velocityTopicName>
  <drift>5.0 5.0 5.0</drift>
  <gaussianNoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</gaussianNoise>
  <velocityDrift>0 0 0</velocityDrift>
  <velocityGaussianNoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</velocityGaussianNoise>
</plugin>

<!-- Groundtruth plugin -->
<plugin name="robot_groundtruth_sim" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
  <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
  <topicName>groundtruth</topicName>
  <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
  <frameName>map</frameName>
  <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
  <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
</plugin>

<!-- IMU plugin -->
<plugin name="robot_imu_sim" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate> 
    <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
    <frameID>robot_link1</frameID>
    <topicName>/robot/IMU</topicName>
    <xyzOffset>0.0 0.0 0.0</xyzOffset>
    <rpyOffset>0.0 0.0 0.0</rpyOffset>
    <gaussianNoise>0</gaussianNoise>
    <accelDrift>0.5 0.5 0.5</accelDrift>
    <accelGaussianNoise>0.35 0.35 0.3</accelGaussianNoise>
    <rateDrift>0.0 0.0 0.0</rateDrift>
    <rateGaussianNoise>0.00 0.00 0.00</rateGaussianNoise>
    <headingDrift>0.0</headingDrift>
    <headingGaussianNoise>0.00</headingGaussianNoise>
</plugin>
```

Here is the tf tree:
[image: image description]

I ran the gmapping node. So because of this node, there is a connection between odom and map links. But there is no connection between odom and base_link.

I also tried to add a node to make the connection between these two links, but when I do **rosrun tf view_frames** nothing changes.

**Edit:** I realized that the transform from odom to base_link is computed and broadcast by one of the odometry sources. So, I modified the following node. Now, when I do "rotopic echo odom", the information is getting updated correctly, but there is still no link between odom and base_link. Actually, I tried to do something similar to this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom). If I run [it](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) , the link between base_link and odom is provided, but I don't know what is wrong with my code that doesn't make the connection between link.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>

class OdomTf{

public:
    OdomTf();
    void getInfo(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);
    ros::Time current_time;
    void publishOdom();
    nav_msgs::Odometry odom;

private:  
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    ros::Subscriber data_sub_;
    ros::Publisher data_pub_;
};

OdomTf::OdomTf(){
    data_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("groundtruth", 1, &OdomTf::getInfo, this);
    data_pub_ = nh_.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom", 10);
}
void OdomTf::getInfo(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
{   
    tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;

    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;

    current_time = ros::Time::now();

    odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
    odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
    odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";
    odom_trans.transform.translation.x = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.y = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.z = msg->pose.pose.position.z;

    odom_trans.transform.rotation.x = msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;
    odom_trans.transform.rotation.y = msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;
    odom_trans.transform.rotation.z = msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;
    odom_trans.transform.rotation.w = msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;

    odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

    //next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
    odom.header.stamp = current_time;
    odom.header.frame_id = "odom";
    odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";

    //set the position
    odom.pose.pose.position.x = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
    odom.pose.pose.position.y = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
    odom.pose.pose.position.z = msg->pose.pose.position.z;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.x = msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.y = msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.z = msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.w = msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;

    odom.twist.twist.linear.x = msg->twist.twist.linear.x;
    odom.twist.twist.linear.y = msg->twist.twist.linear.y;
    odom.twist.twist.angular.z = msg->twist.twist.linear.z;
}

void OdomTf::publishOdom()
{
    data_pub_.publish(odom);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_tf_publisher");
    OdomTf odomtf;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        odomtf.publishOdom();
        ROS_INFO("The Pose is updated");
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know what changes are necessary to solve this problem?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234040/tf-tree-problem-with-map-%3Eodom-%3Ebase_link/) by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
How did you estimated state of robot? The creating link between `odom` and `base_link` is job of localization node. It may be `robot_pose_ekf` or it will be controller's node directly: just set `/mobile_base_controller/enable_odom_tf` to `true`.

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-05-10**:
@Orhangazi44 For localizing the robot, I've used gmapping. I am using gazebo, and I want to see the changes of the coordinate frames for each joint in Rviz as my legged robot walks in gazebo. I am using ros_control for gazebo, so I think I can't use the option you said. Do you know what I should do?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
You probably running via `controls.launch` file. And probably with `controls.yaml` file. Change `enable_odom_tf` parameter in `controls.yaml`. If you are not, try adding these files to you structure. Here is examples in following comments:

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
`<node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner"`
`args="mrp2_joint_publisher mobile_base_controller --shutdown-timeout 1" />`

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-05-10**:
@Orhangazi44 Thanks. I am using control.launch with control.yaml file. I think I need to add enable_odom_tf option somewhere. I haven't done it before.

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-05-10**:
@Orhangazi44 is `enable_odom_tf` part of a controller driver for wheeled robots? Can I use it for legged robots?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
I don't know, We are using this parameter to creating transform between `base_footprint` and `odom` for wheeled robots. But I think it must be work. Because other transformations are ok with `base_link`.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-11**:
@Orhangazi44 @MahsaP a minor correction: typically, the tf `odom->base_link` comes from the base controller of the robot, not the localization. localization reads this tf. `odom->base_link` is what the robot thinks it has moved based on motor encoders

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-11**:
I'm partly new to ROS and continuing to learn. Thanks a lot for correction Sir!

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-05-11**:
@mig Thanks for your explanation. You know I just added the above plugins to .gazebo file. When I echo the topics the data from each is updated. But, I don't know how to obtain the link between for example odom and base_link. The robot walks correctly in gazebo, but in rviz base_link is fixed.

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-05-11**:
I have found this explanation from [here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html):
The transform from odom to base_link is computed and broadcast by one of the odometry sources. So, the odom topic is published from the plugin, but the connection between links have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you are just "routing"  what you receive on the input odometry topic through to the tf broadcast.
Do a `rostopic echo` on the input odometry and check what you have in the `pose` field. I'm guessing this is all zero (and 1 for the `orientation.w`).

You'll have to integrate the pose given the velocities of the input odometry topic. Check the lines [30-55](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom#CA-e6fba4e92077b8226b57e9a62abdb695f9f5a84f_30) in the link you provided.

---

*EDIT*

Hmm, maybe some timing issue. I see that you declare the `odom_broadcaster` only in the callback.
It could be, that you try to broadcast when this is not connected/advertised properly at the rosmaster, and as you do this in each step, this never gets properly sent out...

Can you try declaring it not in the callback but as a class member?

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-05-12**:
@mig actually I can see the updates in the pose, and I think updates are reasonable, but the tf is not broadcast for some reason.
e.g.
pose:
position:
x: 12.6596827148
orientation:
w: 0.997481774674

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-05-12**:
@mig I did what you said. Now it's working :)

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-12**:
great :-) happy to help